# HTTPMetadataProvider over HTTPS handshake failure

Tags: java, ssl, saml, adfs

for first sorry for my english.

I'm trying to load IDP federation metadata xml from remote through https with

```
           <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value type="java.lang.String">https://servername/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <!-- Timeout for metadata loading in ms -->
                        <value type="int">5000</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
```

but I get always the same error:

```
avax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSession was invalid: Likely implicit handshake failure: Set system property javax.net.debug=all for details
```

I've downloaded the SSL cert from IIS and imported into my JDK cacerts but nothing changed.

It's a self signed certificate so I tried to import it into my custom keystore and setting the bean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer"/>
```

as indicated here: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-idp

but the same error occured.

I also enable -Djavax.net.debug=ssl and I could seen the ssl certificate loaded correctly from my JDK cacert.

The SSL self-signed cert will expire in 2027 so It's valid.

What do you think can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

This is the SSL Debug output about metadata refresh:

```
Attempting to fetch metadata document from 'https://adfstest.myserver.lan/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml'
2018-02-16 08:15:35,636 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] (HttpConnection.java:692) - Open connection to adfstest.myserver.lan:443
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1501922583 bytes = { 113, 176, 237, 151, 218, 255, 124, 60, 132, 140, 185, 139, 62, 53, 179, 120, 2, 218, 40, 214, 57, 47, 207, 219, 192, 191, 138, 50 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
localhost-startStop-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 249
localhost-startStop-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
localhost-startStop-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
localhost-startStop-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
localhost-startStop-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
localhost-startStop-1, called closeSocket()
localhost-startStop-1, IOException in getSession():  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
localhost-startStop-1, called close()
localhost-startStop-1, called closeInternal(true)
2018-02-16 08:15:35,721 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] (HttpMethodDirector.java:404) - Closing the connection.
2018-02-16 08:15:35,722  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] (HttpMethodDirector.java:439) - I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException) caught when processing request: SSLSession was invalid: Likely implicit handshake failure: Set system property javax.net.debug=all for details
2018-02-16 08:15:35,723 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] (HttpMethodDirector.java:443) - SSLSession was invalid: Likely implicit handshake failure: Set system property javax.net.debug=all for details
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSession was invalid: Likely implicit handshake failure: Set system property javax.net.debug=all for details
```

That broken pipe exception sounds weird

Another strange thing is that that ssl cert it was already loaded in my JDK cacert because of another SAML request in another project that works correctly.

Comment: Add the output of `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl `. Maybe we can see in it what went wrong.

Comment: [Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/233).

Comment: `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` - that is the server closing the connection. The client sent the handshake _WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 249_ and the server closed the connection.